# CakePHP radio and checkboxes

Tags: cakephp, radio-button

i've a ctp code snippet of a radio button input:

```
 $this->Form->input('something', array(
       'type' => 'select',
       'multiple' => 'radio',
       'options' => array('true' => 'condition 1','false' => 'condition 2'))
);
```

but i cannot handle correctly into the controller the request data passed.
It returns an array like this: `array((int) 0 => 'true')`. So when i try to insert it into the database (I catch it via `$this->request->data['Model']['something']`), it returns a database error, 'cause of the array.
How should I handle it correctly?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$options = array('true' => 'condition 1', 'false' => 'condition 2');
$attributes = array('legend' => 'something');
echo $this->Form->radio('something', $options, $attributes);
```

For **Check boxes** Try this

```
$options = array('true' => 'condition 1', 'false' => 'condition 2');
echo $this->Form->input('something', array(
                'options' => $options ,
                'label' => 'something',
                'div' => false,
                'type' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'multiple' => 'checkbox'
            ));
```

[For more detail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Comment: yeah that works that way! Do you know what do I have to do for this in order to work also with checkboxes, in another piece of code I have?